# Is there a way in google sheets to select a list of cells as an array to be used as a parameter in a connected sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a new google sheet set up to query my database via a connected sheet.

The query returns a list of our shops and their sales per year. Each shop has an ID.

I am able to set Cell A1 in another, reference sheet, to be a parameter in the query. This way the connected query only returns results for that particular store ID.

When using this, I really want to put an `IN` function into my query. The connected query would then look something like.

```
SELECT * FROM shops where shops.id in (@RANGE)
```

And @RANGE would be A2:A as an array.

I've had success naming each cell as a new parameter and then:

```
SELECT * FROM shops where shops.id in (@REFERENCE1, @REFERENCE2)
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: My sheet currently has two tabs. One is a connected sheet linked to our bigQuery database and the other has a list of Shop ID's.

The connected sheet has a query built into it to get all shops. =Query could be part of the solution but I'm not sure

Comment: could you share a sheet with dummy copy pasted values as an example ? and an example output please ?

Comment: Don't use `A2:A` as it return nulls from bottom of data down to Sheet.getMaxRows().  Use range(2,1,sh.getLastRow()...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but the easiest way I found was to convert to regex.

```
select (@POSTCODES) as test, postcode
  from `postcode.au_towns`
  where  regexp_contains(@postcodes,safe_cast(postcode as string))
```

Where @POSTCODES is a gsheet string using a formula like join("|",UNIQUE(Sheet1!D2:D)).

Just make sure to remove the extra "|" generated using something like
left(B2,len(B2)-1)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(FILTER(D3:D,D3:D<>"",E3:E),"WHERE Col1 <> ''",9^99)," ","|")
```

This filters a column of store IDs based on which ones have been selected, and coverts that into a text string similar to the query you have been using.  Producing something like `"A1|A3|A7"`.

The query then just points to that result for the `contains` criteria.

Note that if your range of store IDs to report on is built in some other fashion, you just need to point to its range, instead of using the filter I have.

See a sample sheet here.  This also shows a merged example of the two formulas, to produce the report all from one formula.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11uMa7CNcTXBnnpWGSIC_WvGSa-P2GTLQ2T7GvTgY4oM/edit?usp=sharing

Let us know if this helps you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Google_Sheet_ID_Can_Be_Find_In_URL", "Sheet_Name!Range(you want to query)"),"SELECT * ")`

or

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Google_Sheet_ID_Can_Be_Find_In_URL", "Sheet_Name!A2:A"),"SELECT * ")`

or

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Google_Sheet_ID_Can_Be_Find_In_URL", "Sheet_Name!Range"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2='shops.id'")")`

`IMPORTRANGE()` method import data from another worksheet. In the parameter, you type google sheet id from the url with quotes, type the desired sheet name end with `!` Then you type the range from that sheet you want to query. When you wrap it with the outer `QUERY()` method, you can query the data from that range such as `A2:A` by selecting specific columns including the column with the range or `*` from that sheet name

When you're using `IMPORTRANGE()` method, it's going to return an array.  The selected columns have to label in numeric like `"SELECT Col 1, Col 2, Col 3"`